# SQL drop-down select display into PHP table with headers only on top

Tags: php, html, sql

I am pulling stuff from a DB and populating it into a drop-down select. When the user selects the query, I want it to be displayed in a table (which it is now). ***But the problem is with the format. I want the headers to be displayed just on the top of the table rather than for every single row.*** What is wrong with my code? Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks in advance.

## Resulting page of code:

[image]

## Desired format (table headings just on top):

[image]

```
<?php
      session_start(); 
      if(!isset($_SESSION['EmployeeID'])){
          $URL="Logon.php";
          header ("Location: $URL");
    }
    ?> 
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Orders Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Orders Information Page</h1>
    <form action="Orders.php" method="post">
    <?php
    require "Information.php";
    try{
        $database="Northwind";  
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $conn->setArribute(PDO::ATT_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Could not open database.";
    }
    $lname= $_POST['txtFirstName'];
    $extension = $_POST['txtLastName'];

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $_SESSION['OrderID']=$_POST['selOrder'];
    }  //end if is a post 

    echo "<select name='selOrder'>";
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE EmployeeID=? ORDER BY CustomerID ASC");
    if ($sql->execute(array($_SESSION['EmployeeID']))) {
      while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        echo "\n\t<option value='" . $row['OrderID'] . "'";
        if(isset($_SESSION['OrderID']) && $_SESSION['OrderID']== $row['OrderID']){
            echo " selected='selected' ";
            }
        echo ">";
        echo "Cust:" . $row['CustomerID'] . " ordered on " . $row['OrderDate'];
        echo "</option>";
      }
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>

    <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <?php   
        if(isset($_SESSION['OrderID'])){

            echo "<h3>Order Details</h3><p>";
            $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders, orderdetails, products WHERE orders.OrderID=orderdetails.OrderID AND products.ProductID=orderdetails.ProductID AND orders.OrderID=? ");
    if ($sql->execute(array($_SESSION['OrderID']))) {
      while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    echo "<table border = '1'> 
    <tr>
    <th>Order ID</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    </tr>";                             

    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['OrderID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['OrderDate'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
      }
    }
    echo "</p>";
            }
        $conn =null;
    ?>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I understand the problem very poorly, or do not understand at all, but is

```php
...
echo "<table border = '1'> 
<tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<th>Order Date</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
</tr>";                             
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['OrderID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['OrderDate'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
...
```

not what you are looking for? Eg displaying the `<th>`'s only once?

Answer (score 1):

This is not very difficult, you just made a little mistake.

Get the

```
<tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<th>Order Date</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
</tr>";
```

part out of the while loop, just before the while loop, and it will work like how you want it to.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

move

```
"<table border = '1'><tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<th>Order Date</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
</tr>";
```

(and while you're at it the `echo "</table>";`)
out of the while loop:

```
echo "<table border = '1'><tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<th>Order Date</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
</tr>";    
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['OrderID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['OrderDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

  }
echo "</table>";
```

note that you had two extra curly braces that weren't doing anything.